# Unable to install pip and other packages on WSL via Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cs50

I am trying to set up local development environment, however, unable to install pip and other packages.

This is the command I run: `sudo apt install python3-pip`

These are the error messages:

```
Ign:1 <url> archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.35-0ubuntu3.4
Ign:2 <url>archive.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.15.0-89.99
Ign:3 <url>archive.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.35-0ubuntu3.4
Ign:4 <url>archive.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.6
Ign:5 <url>archive.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libc-devtools amd64 2.35-0ubuntu3.4
Ign:6 <url>archive.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpython3.10-dev amd64 3.10.12-1~22.04.2
Ign:7 <url>archive.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3.10-dev amd64 3.10.12-1~22.04.2
Err:1 <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.35-0ubuntu3.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:2 <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.15.0-89.99
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:3 <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.35-0ubuntu3.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:4 <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:5 <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libc-devtools amd64 2.35-0ubuntu3.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:6 <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpython3.10-dev amd64 3.10.12-1~22.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:7 <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3.10-dev amd64 3.10.12-1~22.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-dev-bin_2.35-0ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.15.0-89.99_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.35-0ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff5_4.3.0-6ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-devtools_2.35-0ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.10/libpython3.10-dev_3.10.12-1%7e22.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch <url>security.ubuntu<.com>/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.10/python3.10-dev_3.10.12-1%7e22.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I found some references online, and tried running these commands,
but the problems persist:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt update --fix-missing
```

Is there a way to understand what's causing this, and subsequently, a workaround?

Comment: The title says, *"via VSCode"*, but is that the case? It sounds like this is a general WSL problem that is occurring for you in the terminal, correct?  My first thought would have been that `sudo apt update` hadn't been run, but you say that you've done that.  Did the error messages change at all, or are they still the same?  Also, you say, *"and other packages"* - Is this *all* packages or do some work?  If it's *all* packages and not VSCode related, I'd like to suggest moving this over to our sister site, [Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com) where it's more likely to get the proper expertise.